# How to skip current page and write to next page?

Tags: java, itext

In my case, while creating the document, I want to switch to next page, event if the current page limit is not reached. Suppose I have multiple tables and want to write each table at different pages.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`Document.newPage()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Document.html#newPage%28%29) to start a new page.